# magento 2 change the slider

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, fotorama-slider, fotorama

I want to disable Magento 2 default fotorama image slider and need to set slick slider. How to disable the slider? How to get images for the custom slider.

Comment: can you check below answer,if it match your requirement mark is valid answer, so others can use if they have have concern, if anymore help required on this let us know

Answer (score 1):

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\gallery.phtml
```

Override this file in  your theme with respective path.

Change `mage/gallery/gallery` to your slider and update configuration as your need.

try to keep configuration same so you can manage via `etc/view.xml`

hope this will help for you, still have some concern please share the your slider library so we can try to change `fotorama` to `your slider`.

Comment: is there any way I can show thumbnail and dots both on the gallery slider?I need to show both

Comment: @jayeshmali can you share detail info or any kind of link so i can check your concern more clearly, because your question was to change slider fotorama to your slider.

Comment: @Kanhaiyalal can you check this? 
 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/302569/magento-2uncaught-typeerror-slick-is-not-a-function-slick-slider